# How to set finish date in excel

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

i'm using google sheets and i have a little logic prob,

in one cell i have state `In Process, Done`
In other cell i have finish date

i whant to be able to insert date automaticly after the state is Done and it's ok
**BUT**, everytime that i enter the sheet the date is updated to corrent date

what i tried

```
IF(A1="Done",TODAY(),"")
```

how can i check if the cell have value dont do anything

tried use ISBLANK but without success

Comment: of course, assuming you want the date to be fixed and doesn't change after you've entered it you can either:

- copy-paste values once the formula is calculated
- use a macro to do that your you based on "a trigger"

Comment: it's to big to explane? i didn't work with excel on daily basis ?

Comment: Well, this isn't a "hey, would someone please write some code for me"-forum. We would love to help you out with code you've written or problems you encounter, but the aim is not to do someone else's work. For more info about questions, please visit the help section.

Comment: @Lambik Ok,, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To input date right to cell next to the one which changed to "Done"
Try this:

```
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getDisplayValue() == 'Done' ) {
   var nC = r.offset(0, -1);
   nC.setValue(new Date());
} else if (r.getDisplayValue() != 'Done' ) {
   var bC = r.offset(0, -1);
    bC.setValue('');
 }
}
```

Should do the work for you :)

Comment: awesome i see i can add scripts and use it in the cell's perfect thank you

Comment: now i need to see where i'm giving the permissions for the script to write to the cell

Comment: on this page: https://script.google.com/home find and open your script, and click on "play" button first ( you have to manualy start it first) it should ask for permission, after that i suggest just for backup solution to click on "clock like" button and setup up Onedit trigger ( sometimes it doesnt work just from script thats why its googd to setup it here also ), glad i could help